# How to see all elements of current symbol in Flash CS5

Tags: flash, symbols, movieclip, flash-cs5

I'm dealing with multiple hard to find/small/transparent elements within nested MovieClips in Flash CS5.  Is there no outline window where I can get to an element through a tree format vs having to look around on the stage?  The closest thing I've found is the Movie Explorer window, but it doesn't go any deeper than the scene level?  But what about symbols with their own timelines?

Answer (score 1):

you could select everything and then use 'distribute to layers'  then clicking on each layer will select that element.

it makes it a little easier to select things.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to break up the given layer, just want to know what's in it.